# Numeric Sitecore ContentHub Localization IDs?

Tags: multilingual, content-hub

We have ContentHub in addition to our Sitecore platform. From ContentHub, we import asset metadata so that we can represent it in Sitecore and pass that metadata along to Coveo, which we use for Search, etc.

In the integration project, we have some code that maps Entity information on import. We have the following code in place to map "Localization IDs" from a numeric value which appears to be coming from ContentHub to an ISO 639-compliant string (e.g., `de-DE`, `en-US`).

```csharp
// ...
case 102978:
    return "de-DE";
case 51306:
    return "en-AU";
case 51298:
    return "en-GB";
case 51303:
    return "en-MY";
case 746:
    return "en-US";
case 51301:
    return "es-ES";
case 51307:
    return "es-MX";
case 51308:
    return "fr-CA";
case 51299:
    return "fr-FR";
case 51302:
    return "it-IT";
case 51304:
    return "ja-JP";
case 51309:
    return "pt-BR";
case 51300:
    return "pt-PT";
case 51305:
    return "zh-CN";
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out where these numeric IDs are defined or coming from. They do not fit an ISO spec that I'm aware of, and the numeric IDs do not line up with [LCID standards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a). Are these some sort of ContentHub convention that I can't locate in their documentation, or is this possibly configured somewhere in my ContentHub instance and I simply cannot find it?

Answer (score 1):

Right, so it was so simple I overlooked it for *several* hours, and of course the answer appeared as soon as I posted my question.

Those are the *Content Hub Entity IDs* of the locales in question.

As you were.

[image]